# Erroring or Erring?

Tags: errors

Is it more correct to say a computer program is `erroring out`, or it is `erring out`? Or are both statements grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Only the former makes sense to me. To err is human, after all.

Comment: Not a dup - the other is about `errored` this is about `erroring`

Comment: Not a dup - the other questions are regarding technical messages in a program, this is conversational

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**erroring**

[error](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/error#Verb) (*third-person singular simple present* **errors**, *present participle* **erroring**, *simple past and past participle* **errored**)

Comment: Note the American Heritage Dictionary (which I tend to favor as the ultimate authoritative source for US English) does not include `error` as a verb: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=error

So `erring` would be correct, but `erroring` would not, which agrees with the autocorrect on Mac OS / Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that neither one is correct (from a programmer).  You could say "... has an error and crashed ..." ("crashed" being the technical term for a program that suddenly stops or breaks down - except for airplane-related programs).

But that's American usage - British programmers may differ.

Comment: I'm an American programmer and I hear "error" used as a verb all the time, often in exactly OP's construction.

Comment: As an American Software Analyst I hear, and use, "erroring out" quite frequently when discussing certain types of crashes with end users.